# Conky show RAM without buffers or cache

Tags: ram, conky

I am wondering if there's a way to get Conky to show the RAM that is in use minus the buffers and cache.

When I close a program, the RAM usage goes down in HTOP, but in conky it stays the same. So I'd like to see it represented correctly on Conky.

Note in this picture, HTOP shows that there's 1300mb of RAM used, and Conky shows 2.15 because it includes cache and buffers.

Here's the chunk of Conky code that deals with RAM

`${font Arial:bold:size=10}${color White}MEMORY ${color DarkSlateGray}${hr 2} $font${color DimGray}MEM $alignc $mem / $memmax $alignr $memperc%
$membar`

[image: conky ram is more than HTOP green bar]

Comment: It will be helpful if you could include your conkyrc in the question.

Comment: Okay, I've added it. Thanks, that's a good point.

Comment: Make sure that the no_buffers setting in your conkyrc is set to yes like this: "no_buffers yes"

Comment: Thanks @BasharatSial That seemed to be the solution. If you'd like to post as an answer, I can + your response. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conky can show actual amount of RAM being used plus cached memory or just the former one. To toggle between two, You can use buffer settings:

If `no_buffers yes` Conky will show only actual amount of RAM being used.

If `no_buffers no` Conky will show actual amount of RAM + Cached memory

Comment: Just note that cache != buffer, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6345020/1986995