# conky RAM usage - does not show large file in ram disk (tmpfs)

Tags: ram, conky

My conkyrc file contains the following:

```
${color grey}RAM Usage:$color $mem/ $memmax - $memperc% ${membar 4}
```

This shows RAM usage numerical values and a bar, for example "`1.01GiB/  7.79GiB - 13%  xx___________`".

I set up a ramdisk and copied a large file to it.  `df -h` returns the following:

```
tmpfs              3,0G    1,1G  2,0G  36% /mnt/ramdisk
```

Why, with a 1,1G file in RAM, does conky still report RAM usage as 1.02Gib?  Where is the large file stored, if not in RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following provides info about RAM disk usage at a quick glance, i.e. how much memory is committed to a specific ramdisk.  It can easily be integrated into a conkyrc:

```
mkdir -pv /mnt/ramdisk/.ramdisk

DF_RESULTS_FILE=/mnt/ramdisk/.ramdisk/df_ramdisk_results.txt
df -h | grep -e /mnt/ramdisk > $DF_RESULTS_FILE 

DF_RESULTS_STRING=$(cat $DF_RESULTS_FILE)
DF_RESULTS_details=($DF_RESULTS_STRING)

printf "RAM Disk Usage: %s /%s\n" ${DF_RESULTS_details[2]} ${DF_RESULTS_details[1]}
```

The following fullfills all of my needs as it reports actually on all instances of a `tmpfs` mount:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rdu2.sh  -  ramdisk usage statusline statistics (version 2.2)

mkdir -pv /mnt/ramdisk/.ramdisk

# Change to /mnt/ramdisk for a specific drive
# or change it to something else or any other information
DF_MONITORED=tmpfs
DF_RESULTS_DIR=/mnt/ramdisk/.ramdisk
DF_RESULTS_FILE=$DF_RESULTS_DIR/rdu2.2_generic_results.txt

#the following lines are for people who haven't thought about doing "ps -A | grep rdu2"
#SCRIPT_PID=$(echo $$)
#printf "%d" $SCRIPT_PID > $DF_RESULTS_DIR/temp_script_pid.txt

printf "rdu2 executing to... [%s]\n" $DF_RESULTS_FILE 

printf "[%s]" $DF_RESULTS_FILE > $DF_RESULTS_FILE

while [ 1 ]
do
# Adding raw numbers and  translating to human-readable
# Display to screen and write to a file
    df | grep -e $DF_MONITORED > $DF_RESULTS_DIR/temp_df_tmpfs.tsv

    TOTAL_MEM_STRING=$(awk '{s+=$2} END {printf "%.0f", s}' $DF_RESULTS_DIR/temp_df_tmpfs.tsv  | awk 'function human(x) { s=" KiB MiB GiB TiB EiB PiB YiB ZiB"; while (x>=1024 && length(s)>1) { x/=1024; s=substr(s,5) }; s=substr(s,1,4); return sprintf( "%.2f%s", x, s) } { gsub(/^[0-9]+/, human($1)); print }')
    TOTAL_MEM_STRING_details=($TOTAL_MEM_STRING)
    USED_MEM_STRING=$(awk '{s+=$3} END {printf "%.0f", s}' $DF_RESULTS_DIR/temp_df_tmpfs.tsv  | awk 'function human(x) { s=" KiB MiB GiB TiB EiB PiB YiB ZiB"; while (x>=1024 && length(s)>1) { x/=1024; s=substr(s,5) }; s=substr(s,1,4); return sprintf( "%.2f%s", x, s) } { gsub(/^[0-9]+/, human($1)); print }')
    USED_MEM_STRING_details=($USED_MEM_STRING)

    printf "%8s%s%8s\r" "$USED_MEM_STRING" " /" "$TOTAL_MEM_STRING"
    printf "%8s%s%8s" "$USED_MEM_STRING" " /" "$TOTAL_MEM_STRING" > $DF_RESULTS_FILE

# Typical format for a conkyrc: 
# # ramdisk usage
# # NOTE: the ${tail logfile lines} is internal to conky; do not confuse with bash's tail command line program
# ${color grey}tpmfs Usage rdu2:$color ${tail /mnt/ramdisk/.ramdisk/rdu2.2_generic_results.txt 1}

    sleep 1.32s
done
```

Called at boot and referenced in conky, the latter script contributes to producing the following text:

```
tmpfs Usage (rdu2): 96.14 MiB /3,42 GiB
```

The values update 'live' when copying a large file to a ramdisk.

Comment: Adding up all tmpfs's and logging to a file could be accomplished with just df and some pipes... `df -h -t tmpfs --total |tail -n 1|tr -s [:space:]|cut -d " " -f 3` optionally tee to a log file. And MemTotal from grep'ing /proc/mem or `free`. All inside a conky exec or two

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is just that conky is not counting that memory as "used" memory.

What is "used" and what is "available" memory is not a simple black and white in Linux or any modern OS.  For example, the system cache (including the hard disk cache) is "used" in the sense that memory is allocated to it, but is "free" in the sense that it's only taking up otherwise available RAM, and will naturally shrink as less RAM becomes available to it.

**tmpfs** is a virtual filesystem which behaves a little like system cache in many respects, in that it has files mapped in RAM taking up memory that would otherwise be "free", except they aren't duplicates of files that also exist on permanent disk-based storage.  With tmpfs, if there ceases to be enough free RAM to keep them in memory, it will swap those files out to the swap partition instead.

Thus for the same reason it makes sense to sometimes think of cache memory as free, in some respects it also makes sense to think of tmpfs memory as free, because that memory is still available for use by other applications.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  I could confirm your explanation with `free` which reports a lot more memory used than that used by just the OS.  I then found this which can produce something closer to the result that I was expecting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/136576/conky-show-ram-without-buffers-or-cache ... Ideally though I would wish to see RAM used  by OS + RAM used by dynamic ram disk (excluding the free space).